# Trying to compare two managers by overriding equals

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a system where first the system check if the details of the manager is already registered in the system. If yes then it opens a menu for them, if not it asks them to try again. Now, I'm checking if the details that the manager entered are already in the system by using `arraylist.contains()` but it always gives me false even if the details are the same. What could be wrong with my code?

Here is my code with the classes I'm using:

this is my main :
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager manager = null;
    String name;
    String location = null;
    String password;
    String familyName;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String id = null;
    DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Deliveries for you");
    System.out.println("PLease sing up the mnagaers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        // SignUp.addAdminToSystem(manager); DataBase.addManager(manager);
        // System.out.println(manager);
        System.out.println("Enter manager " + (i + 1) + " :");
        System.out.println("Enter manager name: ");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter manager family name: ");
        familyName = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter manager location: ");
        location = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter manager password: ");
        password = input.next();
        manager = new Manager(name, familyName, password, location);
        dataBase.addManager(manager);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter admin: ");
    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter family name");
    familyName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter password");
    password = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter location");
    location = input.next();

    Manager m1 = new Manager(name, familyName, password, location);

    if (m1.equals(manager)) {
        System.out.println("m1 is in the array list");
    } else
        System.out.println("its not in the array list");

    input.close();
}
```

}

my dataBase class :

```
     public class DataBase {
    public static ArrayList<Manager> admin;

         public DataBase() {
        admin = new ArrayList<Manager>();

    }
       public void addManager(Manager manager) {
        admin.add(manager);
        Iterator it = admin.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            it.next();
        }
        System.out.println(admin);
    }
}
```

my manager class I tried overriding equals and with/out using hashCode but both didn't work:

```
    public class Manager {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private Members[] member;
    private String location;

public Manager(String firstName, String lastName, String password, String location) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.member = new Members[0];
        this.location = location;
        admins = new ArrayList<Manager>();

    }
//and all the getters/setters
}
```

Comment: I don't see you overriding equals().

Answer (score 1):

Use:

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
...
}

And make your comparisons within the braces.